# javascript jQuery object building

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, navigation

Javascript is not my favorite but I have to do something.

I want to create a special array ( it's might be an object ) that contents datas about elements of the page.

Its needed to have a special structure that would look like this if I could use php instead:

```
$navdata= array(
    'string'=> array( 'key' => $value),
    'string2'=> array( 'key' => $value2),
    'string3'=> array( 'key' => $value3),
)
```

I was tried to create this object via .push() but I still not succeed. Could anyone suggest something?

Answer for the 'why?' question:

I'm making a navigation of a 'one page site' which will use a bunch of animations and navigation elements e.g. arrows, traditional navigation links, pagenums ... etc.

But every way I have tried to collect needed data and use them for animation on the spot the collected data was not correct because counted relatively to viewport that is fixed but I need them relatively to the document.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make an array of objects in javascript?

Does this help you:

```
var navdata = [{
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}, {
    key1: "value2",
    key2: "value3"
}];

var object3 = {
    key1: "value4",
    key2: "value5"
};

navdata.push(object3);

console.log(navdata[2].key1);
```

Edit: As per your comment, try something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    aboutText: function () {
        return $("#about").text();
    },
    aboutTextNoFunction: $("#about").text()
};

console.log(myObject.aboutText());
console.log(myObject.aboutTextNoFunction);
```

You can either store the information in your object as the "aboutTextNoFunction"-field does or simply create functions in your object, which retrives the value after you call the function.

Comment: Yes it's truly object but I need another structure or way to get data from it.. for example:

I have a div via id="about".. I want to get from nav data its properties by navdata['about'].propertyname...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
var navdata = {};

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i+=1) {
    if (i === 0) {  // special case for the first elem
        navdata['string'] = { 'key' : values[i] };
    } else {
        navdata['string' + (i+1)] = { 'key' : values[i] };
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(navdata));
```

Comment: if you could supply a little example of your HTML, I could write a concrete JS object which would read the right keys and values for your case.